# React native TouchableOpacity onPress not working on Android Build (APK)

Tags: react-native, button, mobile, cross-platform, touchableopacity

TouchableOpacity works on the android emulator and on the cell phone, but when I generated the APK, TouchableOpacity didn't work anymore.

what could be happening?

When I click on TouchableOpacity nothing happens, it just makes the opacity animation

the right thing would be to go to the Home screen but it doesn't

does it have something over it like z-index?

**Javascript Code Bellow**

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Image, Text, TouchableOpacity, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {useField} from '@unform/core';
import {Form} from '@unform/mobile';
import {KeyboardAwareScrollView} from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';

import styles from './styles';

import logoImg from '../../assets/logo.png';
import Home from '../Home';

export default function Login() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  function navigateToHome() {
    navigation.navigate(Home);
  }

  return (
    <KeyboardAwareScrollView style={styles.scroll}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={styles.logo} source={logoImg} />
        <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Login" />
        <TextInput
          secureTextEntry={true}
          style={styles.inputPassword}
          placeholder="Senha"
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={navigateToHome}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Entrar</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  );
}
```

**Style Code Bellow**

```
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

export default StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  scroll: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  logo: {
    marginTop: 30,
  },
  input: {
    marginTop: 30,
    padding: 10,
    width: 300,
    height: 56,
    backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
    fontSize: 16,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#8CC63F',
    borderRadius: 4,
  },
  inputPassword: {
    marginTop: 30,
    padding: 10,
    width: 300,
    height: 56,
    backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
    fontSize: 16,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#8CC63F',
    borderRadius: 4,
  },
  button: {
    width: 122,
    height: 66,
    marginTop: 60,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#20565C',
    borderRadius: 4,
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#fff',
    textTransform: 'uppercase',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});
```

Comment: You said you're able to see opacity right. I don't think it's related to zIndex. Add a log and try to check if that shows up in Android studio logcat

Comment: i am using Reactotron and add console.tron.log('click') in the function navigateToHome() the app crashes

Answer (score 0):

update below code like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={()=>this.navigateToHome}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Entrar</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

hope it works for you.

Comment: when I click just the opacity animation happens

Comment: Try going through your navigation code again, I'm sure there is something missing. try adding an alert statement to see if it triggers an alert that confirms the touchable opacity works.

Comment: I created an Alert with the click message it worked normal in the APK the navigation is not working

Comment: is it not a problem in my style code? it is strange that in the emulator it works but in the apk no

Comment: i solved it put ' ' in the function like this navigateToHome { navigation.navigate('Home') }